# log4j 2.x, a new file per day per module

Tags: java, log4j

How can I create log-file in following structure for my Enterprise Java app?

I want to create a directory per Day like `04-20-2013` and then per Module of an application I want to create a file inside that directory.

e.g.

```
/var/xAppLog/
............/04-20-2013/module1.log
............/04-20-2013/module2.log
............/04-20-2013/module3.log
............/05-20-2013/module1.log
............/05-20-2013/module2.log
............/05-20-2013/module3.log
```

How can I achieve this? I am new to Java world.

Comment: did I ask something way too complicated?